# How to implement a sole class of methods inside an external class

Tags: python, class, methods

I have an external class to represent my data `idk`. Inside the class `idk` I want to have another class `change` which will contain various methods to change instances of the class `idk`. What I've tried is below. Note: this is a simplified example of my actual code

```
class idk:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x=1
    self.y=2
  class change:
    def func(self):
      self.x=10
      self.y=100

var=idk()
var.change.func()
print(var.x, var.y)
```

However this gives the error:
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument 'self'

How do I change the code to make it work?

Comment: Why do you want to design your class like this, what benefit do you get over just defining the `func` method directly on the `idk` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, your are getting this error because you are accessing the `func` function as a class attribute and not by an instance of it (putting a class definition inside another class won't make it an instance).

If it makes sense, you cloud put those "change methods" in the `idk` class directly (that would be a normal approach):

```py
class idk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
  
    def func(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 100

var = idk()
var.func()
print(var.x, var.y)  # Output: 10 100
```

If you really want/need to separate those methods, you could do another class. The way I would implement that class is with static methods where all of them recieve an `idk` instance as the first parameter:

```py
class idk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

class idkChanger:
    @staticmethod
    def func(idk_obj):
        idk_obj.x = 10
        idk_obj.y = 100

var = idk()
idkChanger.func(var)
print(var.x, var.y)  # Output: 10 100
```

If you really really want/need to have that "changer" class inside of the `idk` class you can define it there, but this is not common at all. Also, you will have to pass the instance as well, that Changer class:

```py
class idk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

    class Changer:
        @staticmethod
        def func(idk_obj):
            idk_obj.x = 10
            idk_obj.y = 100

var = idk()
idk.Changer.func(var)
print(var.x, var.y)  # Output: 10 100
```

**Final notes:**

You could not mark (decorate) the `func` as static and it will work the same, but this will bring more confution for several reasons (e.g., you would tecnically saying that `func` is an instance method. Which is not, because the objects you want to change are not `Change`'s instances but `idk`'s).

Comment: Hmm it kinda defeats the purpose if I still have to pass var into the function as the convenience of methods is that the instance is automatically passed into the funcrion. Thanks for the response anyways:)